# Emqtt - How to implement ACL for huge no. of clients

Tags: mqtt, iot

I am using Emqtt (emqtt.io) broker for my next application. The scene is - 
I’ll have multiple clients(10,000s) and each of them will be publishing or subscribing to topics. But i want to restrict every client to publish and subscribe only on topics congaing there own client id - For ex- 
Topics will be-

my_device/**12345**/update

my_device/**99998**/update

my_device/**88888**/update

If the middle attribute is the client ID, how can i restrict clients to do a pubs only on that particular topic and no one should be able to subscribe to 
**my_device/#**  and hence receiving all my messages.

I saw ACL plugin, saw this code ( **{allow, {user, "dashboard"}, subscribe, ["$SYS/#"]}**. ) but there i have to define every client manually ? and what if a new user is added, how will i add one more rule automatically ? because with my understanding, this file is loaded on starting up of the broker, right ?. **I want to use ACL based on some database.** Can You help me with that ?

Answer (score 2):

The Emqtt user guide lists a set of plugins that can be used to store the ACL in a database:

http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/guide.html

The links in the that doc are broken, but the projects are hosted under the same git organisation

Answer (score 2):

### A. auth plugin

#### 1. login

https://emqtt.io/docs/v2/guide.html#authentication
lot of ways to check login

- http
- redis/mysql...

#### 2. acl

also can control acl access

- http
- redis/mysql..

but internal conf More efficient

### B. acl internel

the magic var in topic pattern

- %c - clientid
- %u - username

the operation

- subscribe
- publish
- pubsub

#### acl.conf example

allow clientid `XXX` sub `clients/XXX`:

```
{allow, all, subscribe, ["clients/%c"]}.
```

allow username `XXX` pub/sub `clients/XXX`:

```
{allow, all, pubsub, ["clients/%u"]}.
```

deny all other:

```
{deny, all}.
```

https://github.com/emqx/emqx/wiki/ACL-Design#examples
example from v4, but v2 also support `%c` `%u`

#### apply change

```sh
$ emqttd_ctl acl reload
```

NOTE: all cluster node should config

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use a plugin for auth/acl. I prefer mongodb plugin but there are other plugins provided.

From their docson github:[MongoDB plugin setup for emqtt](https://github.com/emqtt/emq_auth_mongo/)

It works great for authentication but I haven't yet been able to subscribe or publish using the plugin settings currently.

Also if the plugins are giving you problems with authentication, try building your emqtt from source